# Keeping values in dataframe based on other column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like the below

| COL1 | COL2 |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | T1 |
| 12 | T2 |
| 12 | T3 |
| 4 | T2 |
| 4 | T3 |
| 7 | T2 |
| 7 | T3 |

I want it to return the following table

| COL1 | COL2 |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | T2 |
| 12 | T3 |
| 4 | T2 |
| 4 | T3 |
| 7 | T2 |
| 7 | T3 |

So pretty much the only rows based on COL1, where COL2 occurs in every group of values in COL1. Assuming its a groupby function I need to do, but cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: pivot, dropna, then melt your data back.

Comment: @QuangHoang kindly post the solution